# Sublime autocomplete scope is "source, text", but not working in html string

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have this autocomplete file:

```
{
  //"scope": "text.html.django",
  "scope": "source, text",

  "completions":
  [
     { "trigger": "variable, curly curly: {{ ... }}", "contents": "{{ $1 }}$0" }
  ]
}
```

And I'm working in this file, whose syntax is set to HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My user profile</title>
    </head>
<body>
  <h1>My user profile</h1>

  <ul>__SPOT_ONE__
     <li>Username: {{ user.username }}</li>
     <li>Email: {{ user.email }}</li>
     <li>Profile picture: <img src=" __SPOT_TWO__ " alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my user-setting:

```
"auto_complete_selector": "text, source",
```

When I type "varcc" at `__SPOT_ONE__`, the `variable, curly curly: {{ ... }}` autotext pops up as expected, but at `__SPOT_TWO__`, it doesn't--whether I press <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> or not. Why is this? I thought the `source, text` scope meant *everywhere*.

Is it possible to get this autotext to also popup in spot two?

Comment: Did you try removing the source altogether?

Comment: Good idea. Html is not "source". I just changed the autocomplete's scope to `"source, text"` to `"text"`. Same results, unfortunately.